# appending list of numbers to new list python

Tags: python

This is kind of hard to describe so I'll show it mainly in code.  I'm taking a List of a List of numbers and appending it to a masterList.
The first list in master list would be the first element of each list.  I would insert 0 in it's appropriate index in the master list.  Then I would move on to the next list.  I would choose the first element of the 2nd list and append it to the second list in the master list, since it's index would be 1, I would insert 0 to the first index of that list.  This is WAY confusing, please comment back if you have any questions about it.  I'll answer back fast.  This is really bugging me.

ex:

```
L = [[], [346], [113, 240], [2974, 1520, 684], [169, 1867, 41, 5795]]
```

What i want is this:

```
[[0,346,113,2974,169],[346,0,240,1520,1867],[113,240,0,684,41],[2974,1520,684,0,5795],[169,1867,41,5795,0]]
```

Comment: This is kind of confusing, indeed. Please post what code you have tried so far. Give some context for why you would want to do this, and people can give better answers. You should read the StackOverflow help for the minimum required steps to ask a programming question here.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want something like

```
>>> L = [[], [346], [113, 240], [2974, 1520, 684], [169, 1867, 41, 5795]]
>>> [x+[0]+[L[j][i] for j in range(i+1, len(L))] for i, x in enumerate(L)]
[[0, 346, 113, 2974, 169], [346, 0, 240, 1520, 1867], 
[113, 240, 0, 684, 41], [2974, 1520, 684, 0, 5795], 
[169, 1867, 41, 5795, 0]]
```

which might be easier to read in expanded form:

```
combined = []
for i, x in enumerate(L):
    newlist = x + [0]
    for j in range(i+1, len(L)):
        newlist.append(L[j][i])
    combined.append(newlist)
```